# Using GO GARCH to optimize a yearly-rebalanced portfolio based on daily data

Tags: time-series, r, garch, modern-portfolio-theory, moments

Is it reliable to optimize portfolio weights on a yearly-rebalanced portfolio based on the Generalized Orthogonal GARCH (GO-Garch) covariance, coskewness, and cokurtosis matrices with the rmgarch R-package using daily estimates of ten stock indices over 5 years?

Comment: If the model describes the data well, it will do fine. If not, then not. There is no general answer to your question.